# how to retrieve array list as hidden parameter into another javascript array object using jquery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

On a jsf page, i have a hidden parameter as

```
h:inputhidden id="feeCode" value="#{feePage.feeCodeList}"
```

This feeCodeList has 4 items in the list.

I have to retrieve all these 4 values as separate strings using jquery. I tried using :

```
$('#feeCode').each(function () {
    var str = $(this).text();
    alert(str); // four times alert should come.
});
```

This statement gives all the 4 items combined in a single string. Say for example: I want 4 items as -

```
One
two
three
four
```

but above expression gives me - `one two three four` - as single string.

Please help me. I am new to jQuery.

Comment: it was simple: I uses: jQuery('#formName\\:feeCode option').each(function(){var str = jQuery(this).text(); alert(str);});

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your bit of code, you are looping over an 'id'. You use '#' to retrieve an element by id. id's should be unique. instead apply a class, something like .feeClass to those four hidden elements and in your code use $(".feeClass").each...